# What was that creature in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

What was that creature used to interrogate Bodhi in Saw's hideout?

It was difficult to understand what Saw was saying.

Comment: Related on Movies.SE: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65783/why-wasnt-the-imperial-pilot-in-rogue-one-made-insane-or-affected/65787#65787

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Bor Gullet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bor_Gullet).

> *Saw turned his head to signal the Tognath. “Bor Gullet,” Saw said.
>
> “Bor Gullet?” Bodhi asked.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novel))</sup></sub>

According to Slashfilm, the creature originally had a larger part in the early script but was relegated to appearing in a a single scene.

> *Bor Gullet, a telepathic cephalopod that Saw Gerrera uses to extract
> information from prisoners, was created by screenwriter Chris Weitz
> “as a way to get inside Jyn’s head.” He gives us a look at the
> original intention of the creature, revealing that the Bor Gullet is
> an “empath, he can understand exactly what you’re thinking, be he also
> feeds off emotion. He likes things like fear and sorrow and sadness.
> And joy, too.”*
>
> *The alien was initially designed as an insect-like creature, but they
> decided to do with an octopod because “his tentacles could go around
> people’s necks and heads and into their ears.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Chris Weitz Created Saw Gerrera’s Alien Interrogation Creature Bor Gullet](http://www.slashfilm.com/early-rogue-one-scripts/2/)</sup></sub>

As to your supplementary questions, **yes, it appears to be telepathic** (or possible Force-using) and **no, there's no indication one way or another as to whether it's native to Jedha.**