# How does Bor Gullet work?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Saw Guerrera used a creature named [Bor Gullet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/150210/70236) to verify whether Bodhi, the Imperial pilot, was telling the truth about Galen Erso.

[image: Bor Gullet]

The creature attached its hand-things to Bodhi's head and supposedly read his mind, and supposedly verified what Bodhi said (also [leaving the latter a bit confused](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/65787/44222)).

The problem is - how did Bor Gullet communicate to Saw Guerrera? How would Saw Guerrera understand whether Bodhi was telling the truth or not, given that Bor Gullet doesn't seem to be able to speak? Would his eyes light red or green, or something?

Comment: Well, he takes his tentacles and... wait, this isn't Japanese porn

Answer (score 6):

Bor Gullet can read minds (obviously), which is how it knows if Bodhi is lying. The novelization gives us this scene from Bodhi's point of view.

> Bor Gullet had taken everything Bodhi was— every intimate thought and
>   dream, every cherished or forsaken memory— and torn through it with
>   tendrils like scalpels. A scrap of first kiss drifted, ripped and
>   sodden, into a pile on the right; a ribbon of kyber crystals floated
>   to the pile on the left, pressed and preserved for further
>   examination.

In regards to the more important part of your question, *"how did Bor Gullet communicate to Saw Guerrera?"*. We don't know. We are not shown this on screen and it is not covered in the novelization. And since this creature has no Legends counterpart, we have nothing to go on.

I speculate that as a telepathic creature, it communicates with Guerrera that way. Probably through impressions rather than speech.